Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{n}{2}}{k}\frac{(-ix)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$
Trying to find nice approximation of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}dx$ here, I met the following sum : $$I_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{n}{2}}{k}\frac{(-ix)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, I tried separating odd and even terms but didn't work for now. Any ideas ?

Too long for a comment.
For $$I_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{n}{2}}{k}\frac{(-ix)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$ Mathematicareturns a closed form in terms of Bessel and Struve functions. But the problem is that, for a given $k$, it leads to Indeterminate since the formula involves in particular terms $\Gamma(1-k)$ which means that, for any $k$, you need to ask for the limit of the expression.
However, looking at specific cases, some patterns seem to appear.
Let $t=-ix$ and consider
$$J_k(t)=\frac{2^k\, e^{-t}\, \Gamma (k+1)\, I_k(t)+(-1)^k \,\, (2k-1)\text{!!}\left(t+e^{-t}-1\right) } {t^2}$$ The first terms are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & J_k(t) \\
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 \\
 3 & t-6 \\
 4 & t^2-10 t+45 \\
 5 & t^3-15 t^2+105 t-420 \\
 6 & t^4-21 t^3+210 t^2-1260 t+4725 \\
 7 & t^5-28 t^4+378 t^3-3150 t^2+17325 t-62370 \\
 8 & t^6-36 t^5+630 t^4-6930 t^3+51975 t^2-270270 t+945945 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Look at $OEIS$ to find possible patterns. For example,

the second highest coefficient is $-\frac{1}{2} (k+2) (k+3)$
the next coefficient is $\frac{1}{8} (k-1) k (k+1) (k+2)$

